# ios-How do I add a navigation controller to a project?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, appdelegate

I have a project and I am having trouble maintaining a navigation controller (which I added through the interface builder). I want to set up a hierarchy because it is saying the views are not added to the window hierarchy. I can move between one view using performSegueWithIdentifier, but using it a second time doesn't work. The problem is it won't allow me to move from one view to another. I have read stuff about messing with the appdelegate or add performForSegue, but I don't know how to using it.

Any suggestions for if I had three views connected like 1 -> 2 -> 3? 
1 and 2 would have performSegueWithIdentifier.

Please and thank you!

Here is my storyboard:
http://s1370.photobucket.com/user/sean_cleveland1/media/Untitled_zpsc9022523.png.html?o=0

Here is my performSegueWithIdentifier functions:

```
//Used in FirstVC.
[self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"firstToSecond" sender: self];
//Used in SecondVC... this doesn't work!
[self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"secondToThird" sender: self];
```

Comment: can you add some code and your storyboard image?

Comment: I updated my question. I don't have any other code relating to navigation controllers.

Comment: @SeanCleveland - You want to move from screen 3 to screen 1 right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First define your third view identifier

[image]

```
- (void)segue
{

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"mySegue" sender:self];

}
```

for only do any condition or operation use below method

```
 - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"mySegue"]) {


    }
}
```

i created simple sample project for you

https://github.com/iDevAndroid/NavigationSample

[image]

try with this. because your are perform model transaction after next line your are using dismiss the model.

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error
{



    [self becomeFirstResponder];
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
[self emailDelivaryedSuccessfully];
];

}



-(void)emailDelivaryedSuccessfully{


        [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"secondToThird" sender: self];
}
```

Comment: I looked at your program, and it works as I want mine to, but I can't use pushToNavigate. How do I?

Comment: which controller to or from  you can't navigate

Comment: SecondViewController to ThirdViewController.

Comment: https://github.com/clevelanm/VideoEmailApp-copy-4    Here is my project. I am trying to get from SecondViewController to the ThirdViewController

Comment: you want to push or model in second to third

Comment: Either way, I have tried both with no luck. I would prefer push, but whatever works.

Comment: Here is the warning I get with your update: Warning: Attempt to present <ThirdViewController: 0x1d1777d0> on <UINavigationController: 0x1c57bb40> while a presentation is in progress!

Comment: you should call  the method after completion of mail dismiss

Answer (score 2):

[image: Your StoryBoard]

Just Control + drag from **"Pop to Main Screen"** `UIButton` to Exit (green button at bottom of scene)
select unwind method declared in first screen with title **"Main"**
e.g.

```
-(IBAction)customUnwind:(UIStoryboardSegue *)sender
{

NSLog(@"Unwind successful");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `performSegueWithIdentifier:` if you are doing it in Storyboard, just comment the code which says `performSegueWithIdentifier:`  and `prepareForSegue:` method in your code and try.
If you are using `performSegueWithIdentifier:` then you need to implement `prepareForSegue:` method also.
ex.

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"firstToSecond" sender: self];
```

//prepareforsegue method

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"firstToSecond"]) {

        SecondViewController *destinationController = [segue destinationViewController];
       //set data if any
    }
}
```

Comment: I added that to the SecondVC, and added the modal to the interface builder (with identifier), but a warning says destinationController is not used, and when ran, it says "Warning: Attempt to present <ThirdViewController: 0x1d17c890> on <UINavigationController: 0x1c57e430> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!"

Comment: are you using modal segue?

Comment: Yes, I am using a modal segue. I tried a push, but my program crashes.

Comment: what error coming when you try push segue, ideally you should use push segue.

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Could not find a navigation controller for segue 'secondToThird'. Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.'

Comment: just remove the segue and add it again and select type as push from your send mail button to ThirdViewController, if still doesn't work then use performSegueWithIdentifier: in send mail method and implement prepareForSegue: method in your SecondViewController.

Comment: https://github.com/clevelanm/VideoEmailApp-copy-4      I got my project on github. Can you look at it? Sorry, I tried, but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: ALToastView files are missing in the project, please add those files